# Can I turn off adb automatically starting when Eclipse is open?

Tags: android

I am using Eclipse to develop both C and Java. I have an Android phone, and when I connect it to my PC, Eclipse (?) automatically starts adb, even though all the Android projects are closed. Is there a way to prevent this happening?

Reason: I want to tether my phone using pda-net to my PC, to use as a modem. pda-net cannot connect if another adb process is running.

Comment: I got a similar problem: I like to use HTC Sync to get my Outlook synchronized with the HTC Hero's calendar. But: as soon as I start Eclipse with Android Plugin, the adb server is started and "steals" the connection to HTC Sync. I did not find **any** way so far to ever get HTC Sync work again; all I can do is eventually restart Windows to get a fresh connection. I think that is essentially the same problem. So... any clue so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Standard Way**

I think that its not possible in any standard way ;)
The best you can do is to have two "instances" of Eclipse (Eclipse doesn't neet real installation you ony have to extract it to a directory so you can have many Eclipses) and have one eclipse for Java+Android and another for C.

It's not the real solution but you will be able to work normally wen developing C.

**Non-standard Way**

Maybe if you create simple bat which will do "adb kill-server" and instantly start pda-net Eclipse will not be fast enough to restart adb server before pda-net connects?

Comment: I figured you just disable USB debugging under Settings->Applications->Development

Comment: I think this is ok, I will make a Java Eclipse installation for Andriod, and keep a separate one for CDT Eclipse.

In CDT Eclipse there is no Settings->Applications menu, I am not sure in 'standard' Eclipse.